# Touch events not always firing

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, touch

My application behaves strangely on a touch terminal. Sometimes, after we start terminal, the application starts, but no touch events are raised on touch. Instead touch events, click events are raised. To make them work I need to restart the terminal.
Example of my touch event:

```
<Button Content="Send">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TouchDown">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnTouchDownSend"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers></Button>
```

We can implement click events for all xaml elements, but I find it not the best way to solve the problem.

Has anyone any ideas what can cause such behavior and how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure this is Wpf ?

Comment: @VivekSaurav. Yes. What makes you think it is not wpf?